# Do I need to use window.onReady() after embedding a script asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, dom, asynchronous

I'm implementing functionality that loads a script asynchronously. After the XHR has completed, I insert the code into the document and call a callback method. The callback method uses that dynamically loaded code.

What I am wondering is that does my callback get called before the appended script is parsed? Do I need to use window.onReady() and let the browser engine parse the appended script and fire window.onReady() and just then call my callback method?

Please do not tell me to use `<your favority library here>`, because I am doing this to learn.

Edit: Or, should I insert a script element with the `src` and `async` set, and listen to the script element's `readystatechange` event?

Comment: How do you insert the code into the document?

Comment: What event triggers your callback function?

Comment: By `window.onReady()` I'm just referring to `DOMContentLoaded` and the tricks that work on older browsers. I'm planning to insert the script into the head section of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how you are loading it.

You could load a script, and then just eval() the responseText after you have loaded it.

Or, you could also `document.createElement('script')`, and then call the callback method.

Pusuedocode:

```
load_xhr('path/to/js', function onReady (responseText) {

eval(responseText);

//OR

var script = document.createElement('script');

script.text = responseText;

//Append element to DOM

//THEN

callback_method();

});
```

> Edit: Or, should I insert a script
>   element with the src and async set,
>   and listen to the script element's
>   readystatechange event?

If you do that, the browser's loading symbol will show. If you load it via XHR, the user won't notice anything.

Comment: Nice "pusuedocode". Anyway, I was interested in whether the script gets always parsed right after the script has been inserted into the DOM or can there be any issues with it.

Comment: A couple of issues there: 1. If you load via XHR, you're limited by the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) except on sites that support CORS and browsers that do likewise. 2. `eval` is not the same as loading a script in the global context, there are all sorts of ramifications around the context in which the code is evaluated. Much, much better off creating a `script` element, even if you load the code via XHR.

Comment: @rFactor, the script gets parsed right away if you use the .text property, not the .innerHTML property

Comment: @georf, @rFactor: In addition to my earlier points, note that not all browsers support assigning to the `text` property on script nodes. Some require that you create and append a text node (`createTextNode`) instead. Re the browser's loading symbol: Some will show it (IE6, IE7, Opera), others won't (Chrome, Firefox, IE9).

Answer (score 1):

> Or, should I insert a script element with the src and async set, and listen to the script element's readystatechange event

The most reliable way is to insert a `script` element with `src` set (don't set `async` or `defer`, no need). For notification that the script has been loaded and parsed, do one of two things:

1. Have the script tell *you* when it's ready. E.g., have it call a function that you already have defined on your page. This is the best thing to do if you control the script you're loading.

   **Example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/emiqe3)):**

   The script:

   ```
   function foo() {
       display("foo() called");
   }
   callWhenReady();
   ```

   The script loading it:

   ```
   var script;
   display("Loading script " + url + "...");
   script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = url;
   document.body.appendChild(script);

   function callWhenReady() {
     display("Script says it's ready, calling foo...");
     foo();
   }
   ```
2. Use a self-rescheduling `setTimeout` loop to look for a symbol the script defines (presumably you know one, you want to call into it). Or you could use `setInterval`, but that requires you keep track of the timer handle and frankly I prefer the control that a self-rescheduling `setTimeout` gives me.

   **Example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/emiqe3/2)):**

   The script (note no callback):

   ```
   function foo() {
       display("foo() called");
   }
   ```

   The loading script:

   ```
   var script;
   display("Loading script " + url + "...");
   script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = url;
   document.body.appendChild(script);
   watchFor('foo');

   function watchFor(fname) {
     if (typeof foo === "function") {
       display("foo detected! Calling...");
       foo();
     }
     else {
       // Not found yet, wait
       setTimeout(function() {
         watchFor(fname);
       }, 50);
     }
   }
   ```
3. **Update**: Re your comment below: If you really know *nothing* about the script being loaded, and you can't have the script call you, it's unclear to me why you need to receive the event. (What will you do, if you don't know any of its global symbols and so can't call any functions it adds?) But most  browsers support the `load` event on `script` elements, and for those that don't (earlier IEs, mostly), there's the `readystatechange` event. For this situation, you could use a combination of those:

   Example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/emiqe3/6)):

   ```
   var script;
   display("Loading script " + url + "...");
   script = document.createElement('script');
   script.onload = function() {
     display("Script loaded (notification via load event). Calling foo just to prove it's loaded, but in the question we wouldn't know about the symbol do we wouldn't be able to call it.");
     foo();
   };
   script.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (script.readyState === "loaded") {
       display("Script loaded (notificaton via readyState). Calling foo just to prove it's loaded, but in the question we wouldn't know about the symbol do we wouldn't be able to call it.");
       foo();
     }
   };
   document.body.appendChild(script);
   script.src = url;
   ```

   That works via the `load` event on Chrome 10, Firefox 3.6, Safari 5, and Mobile Safari; via the `readystatechange` event in IE6, IE7, and IE8; and via *both* events in Opera 11 and IE9.

Comment: I do not know anything about the script being inserted nor do I want to ask the writer of it to implement any specified callbacks. Is there not a way to detect when the script has been parsed, other than that?

Comment: @rFactor: So you're loading a script that you don't know *anything* about? You don't know any global symbols it defines? (E.g., option #2 above.) What will you do with it when it's loaded, then? Anyway, in that case, I've added option #3. It turns out that between `load` and `readystatechange`, you can get a completed notification from just about any browser you need to support.

Answer (score 1):

It depends an what you want to do in your script

Here is an example of injecting in a script before the dom is ready and it calling a callback function.

```
var callback = function() { console.log('hi you called'); };

document.write('<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">// code\n callback();<\/script>');
```

If the script needs to work with the dom then it needs to wait until it's ready otherwise not.

However your solution will need to be tested in all the browsers you wish to support, as the order of script evaluation and execution 
differs in for example IE and FF.